# Cosine similarity between a combination of numerical and text values

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to do a simple content based filtering model on the Yelp dataset with data about the restaurants.
I have a DataFrame in this format

```py
>>> business_df.dtypes
address          object
attributes       object
business_id      object
categories       object
city             object
hours            object
is_open          object
latitude        float64
longitude       float64
name             object
postal_code      object
review_count      int64
stars           float64
state            object
```

Now I'm trying to build a content-based collaborative filtering model where I'm answering the question "Given a restaurant, recommend similar restaurants"

I'm trying to implement a model given under *Content-Based Recommender* here - https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python

Basically, they use some text fields to build a Count Vectorizer matrix and then do a cosine similarity on the rows to get similarity between movies.

They say later that

> Introduce a popularity filter: this recommender would take the 30 most similar movies, calculate the weighted ratings (using the IMDB formula from above), sort movies based on this rating, and return the top 10 movies.

I'm trying to use the Categories, Attributes, Latitude and Logitude (for distance), Stars and Review Count(Stars weighted based on review count - higher number of reviews leads to more weightage for stars) to build a similar model.

But I don't know how to incorporate the numerical columns into the model here. I'm certain I cannot pass the numerical columns into the Count Vectorizer.

Can I build 2 models -- 1 with the text fields and other by simply calculating the cosine similarity(or Pearson correlation) between the numerical columns -- and combine those 2? If yes, how would I do that?

Or could I follow the Data camp model and do the text fields in a model, then use the formula to incorporate ratings? If yes, I would still be unable to do distance based on Latitude-Longitude

Comment: Why do you think cosine distance between numbers is harder than cosine distance between word vectors? Think about the euclidean definition of cosine distance.

Comment: @tripleee I was thinking I cannot add the numbers in the same Count Vectorizer functions that I add the text in and the solution was to do Count Vectorizer on the text and Pearson correlation on the numbers separately. But I'd still not know how to combine those 2 results into something coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the `CountVectorize`r gives you a matrix `C` of shape `(N, m)` where `N` = number of restaurants and m = number of features (here the count of the words).

Now since you want to add numerical features, say you have `k` such features. You can simply compute these features for each movie and concatenate them to the matrix `C`. So for each movie now you will have `(m+k)` features. The shape of `C` will now be `(N, m+k)`. You can use pandas to concatenate.

Now you can simply compute the Cosine Similarity using this matrix and that way you are taking into account the text features as well as the numeric features

However, I would strongly suggest you normalize these values, as some of the numeric features might have larger magnitudes which might lead to poor results. Also instead of the  `CountVectorizer`, TFIDF matrix or even word embeddings might give you better results

Comment: How would I normalize the values? Can you point me to some resources?

Comment: For example, if a restaurant can have zero to five stars, you could normalize this to a float between 0 and 1 (0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)

Comment: @tripleee Ah got it! Also do you have any idea how I can weight the rating on the number of reviews? There are some restaurants with high rating but very low # of reviews

Comment: A simple linear interpolation where the max (or some theoretical maximum) is 1.0 would seem like the obvious solution. Sometimes logarithms make sense when you care more about the order of magnitude than linear proportionality.

Comment: The tutorial you had linked addresses how to come up with a weighted rating. Also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542391/how-to-normalize-reviews-based-on-score